# installing node.js on a new ubuntu machine won't work

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

Ok, I have this whole new machine on which I just freshly installed Ubuntu 12.10. I'm trying to install node.js by following the instructions on [this](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) website. The first time I did that it worked like a charm, but then I had some troubles installing packages because `nodejs --version` and `node --version` gave two different results. I thought then that the best idea was to do a `rm -rf /usr/var/node` or something like that. That resulted in a total mess up of everything.
By trying to call `sudo apt-get install nodejs` again, I get the following error message:

```
[...]
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_0.8.26-1chl1~quantal1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I really tried everything, from `apt-autoremove` to `clean` to whatever, I cannot possibly figure out why this is not working anymore. Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit: it's funny how people gives -1 without even reading the question. If these smart alecks think this question is stupid or inappropriate, they could simply write so or help me out, since I'm struggling with this. Also, removed some of the output, since people cannot read until the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try install the `locales` packages, and run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` to set the locales "en-US" for the system.

Comment: That wouldn't work. I get the following error during the installation of `locales` : `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs-dev : Depends: nodejs (= 0.8.26-1chl1~quantal1) but 0.6.19~dfsg1-5ubuntu1 is to be installed`

Comment: Try remove nodejs first, or force the minimum required version. 0.8 and 0.6 are very different.

Comment: `apt-get install pkg=version`

Comment: `E: Version '0.8' for 'nodejs' was not found` neither works for `0.8.26` which is the one of the error

Comment: Do a `apt-get update`, check what's the available versions for node and force the exact version. I'm not sure what's your sources.list, it may be wrong, or conflict.

Comment: Doesn't work either. Is there a way to clean all my `apt-get` stuff regarding node and do a fresh install?